# Can i have drag and drop from jquery treeview to jquery full calendar

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, fullcalendar

I want that i should be able to drag items from jquery treeview that supports drag and drop.Drop item onto jquery full calendar with database interaction

Comment: what kind of code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2837415/drop-custom-jquery-ui-draggable-in-fullcalendar-plugin/2841709#2841709)... basically you'll have to use a [custom version of fullCalendar](http://github.com/arshaw/fullcalendar/tree/fcdraggable).

Or, maybe you could adapt [this plugin](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2010/05/drag-external-events-into-fullcalendar.html) I put together for use with any version of fullCalendar, until fullCalendar officially releases the drag and drop version.